# Como adicionar uma nova chave em um dicionário?

Tags: python

Tenho o seguinte desafio:

> input : "teste conaz"
>
> output: {'a': 1, ' ': 1, 'c': 1, 'e': 2, 'o': 1, 'n': 1, 's': 1, 't': 2, 'z': 1}

E implementei o seguinte código:

```
    def contabiliza_letras(string):
        dict = {'a':0,'b':0,'c':0,'d':0,'e':0,'f':0,'g':0,'h':0,'i':0,'j':0,'k':0,'l':0,'m':0,'n':0,'o':0,'p':0,'q':0,'r':0,'s':0,'t':0,'u':0,'v':0,'w':0,'x':0,'y':0,'z':0}
        for letra in string:
            if letra == ' ':
                pass
            else:
                 dict[letra] += 1
       return dict

print(contabiliza_letras("teste conaz"))
```

E está funcionando, mas eu queria que, conforme fossem me dadas as letras da string, eu adicionasse no dicionário a chave, de forma que a resposta fosse um dicionário contendo apenas as letras que estão na string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de criar o dicionário já com todas as letras com 0, inicie-o de forma vazia:
`dict={}`

Quando se faz `dict[chaveNova]=NovoValor`, ele já inclui no dicionário caso essa chave não exista.
Além disso, como você quer incrementar a chave, você pode verificar se ela já existe e caso contrário definir como valor inicial "1":

```
def contabiliza_letras(string):
    dict = {}
    for letra in string:
        if letra == ' ':
            pass
        else:
             if (letra not in dict):
                 dict[letra]=1
             else:
                 dict[letra] += 1
    return dict

print(contabiliza_letras("teste conaz"))
```

Comment: Obrigada! Pensando mais um pouco implementei um código bem semelhante. Resolveu o problema! :)

Answer (score 4):

Você pode deixar o dicionário vazio e ir acrescentando as chaves conforme a necessidade, algo assim:

```py
def contabiliza_letras(string):
    dict = {}
    for letra in string:
        if not letra == " ":
            dict[letra] = dict.get(letra, 0) + 1
    return dict
```

E usar o método `.get()` para pegar o valor atual de uma letra já existente, ou zero se ela não existir e somá-la com 1. E no caso da chave não existir ela será automaticamente criada no processo.

O resultado seria assim, mas `{'t': 2, 'e': 2, 's': 1, 'c': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1, 'a': 1, 'z': 1}` no teu exemplo o espaço está sendo considerado, daí é só remover a condição do `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Se nesse desafio você puder utilizar recursos do próprio Python para trabalhar com *collections*, existe o [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) que serve justamente para este propósito:

```
from collections import Counter

sentence = 'teste conaz'
counter = Counter()

for word in sentence:
    counter.update(word)

# [('t', 2), ('e', 2), ('s', 1), (' ', 1), ('c', 1), ('o', 1), ('n', 1), ('a', 1), ('z', 1)] 
print(counter.most_common())
# {'t': 2, 'e': 2, 's': 1, ' ': 1, 'c': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1, 'a': 1, 'z': 1}
print(dict(counter.most_common()))
```

#### [Funcionando no IDEONE](https://ideone.com/fLHe1C)

Se quiser desconsiderar o espaço:

```
from collections import Counter

sentence = 'teste conaz'
counter = Counter()

for word in sentence.split():
    counter.update(word)

# [('t', 2), ('e', 2), ('s', 1), ('c', 1), ('o', 1), ('n', 1), ('a', 1), ('z', 1)]
print(counter.most_common())

# {'t': 2, 'e': 2, 's': 1, 'c': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1, 'a': 1, 'z': 1}
print(dict(counter.most_common()))
```

#### [Funcionando no IDEONE](https://ideone.com/EdFFLf)

Comment: Ficou faltando o espaço em branco no dicionário.

Comment: @Focos thanks. :)